# Create an IEnumerable Queue from two IEnumerables

Tags: c#

I have two `IEnumerable`s, `stockDates` and `stockClosing`, that I want to place in a queue.

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> stockDates = stocks.Select(equity => equity.Date);
IEnumerable<decimal> stockClosing = stocks.Select(equity => equity.Close);

// create a queue
Queue<MovingAverage> movingAverageQueue = new Queue<MovingAverage>();
```

How can I add `stockDates` and `stockClosing` into the newly created `movingAverageQueue`?

Here is the MovingAverage class:

```
namespace myBackEnd.Models
{
public class MovingAverage
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Close { get; set; }

}
}
```

Comment: Show us the `MovingAverage` class (struct?) first.

Comment: Use Union() to unite the two results.

Comment: Looks like you don't need `stockDates` and `stockClosing` but should be projecting `stocks` directly into an enumerable of `MovingAverage` but without knowing what that object is or what you're trying to do, we can't help you. It's also not clear why you need a queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IEnumerable.Zip()` for this, however as the `MovingAverage` class is not shown in the post, I just used examplary properties:

```
movingAverageQueue = stockDates.Zip(stockClosing , (d, c) => new MovingAverage{ Date = d, Average = c});
```

If they are both in stocks and you want average of closing with a date then you can do this:

```
var result = stocks.GroupBy(x=> x.Date.Date)
             .Select(g => new MovingAverage{ Date = g.Key, Average = g.Average()});
```

Note that in `stocks.GroupBy(x=> x.Date.Date)` as `x.Date` is a DateTime, `x.Date.Date` will be its date (without time) so that all with the same date would be equal for grouping.

Comment: @Jam66125 actually it supposed to be g.key. I edited my answer. and You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the Queue constructor `Queue(ICollection)`

```cs
new Queue<MovingAverage>(stocks.Select(stock => new MovingAverage(...))
```

Answer (score 0):

If `movingAverageQueue` is an already existing `Queue`, if could just use [ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.Generic.List%601.ForEach);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) on the `Stocks` `[Enumerable]` and `.Enqueue()` the values in a new `MovingAverage` object:

```
stocks.ForEach(s => movingAverageQueue.Enqueue(new MovingAverage { Date = s.Date, Close = s.Close }));
```